# How to initialize a static array with most values the same but some values different?

Tags: arrays, syntax, static, rust

I would like to use a static or const array, but initialize it using something other than the `[T; N]` syntax. I need to define specific elements but all other values can default to 0 or some other value.

In C, you can do the following:

```c
byte ARRAY[256] = {
    [0x1F] = (1 << 4),
    // Or even simply just this
    [0x46] '\n'
};
```

I've tried something along the lines of:

```
static ARRAY: [u8; 256] = {
    // x is some arbitrary number of elements
    let mut array = [0, x];
    array[i] = 'b',
    array[j] = 'a',
    array[k] = 'd',
    array
};
```

This was merely trial and error based on syntax I know to work for local array declarations. This throws a compiler error saying that blocks in const and static are limited to items and tail expressions. I know that if I enclose an array definition in brackets, then the last line or last expression must be the implicit return.

Additionally, I don't have access to the std library, but I don't think a complex structure would be necessary for something this simple - to index and obtain a value.

I've looked at the Rust macro rules and think that could be a solution, but all the examples I have seen are iterative and incremental.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no Rust equivalent to your C snippet. The [documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/reference/expressions/array-expr.html) shows only 3 simple patterns are allowed:

1. empty
2. value, value, value, etc...
3. value; size

So, currently with array syntax, you can't do it.

[RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0911-const-fn.md) about const function now allow:

```rust
static ARRAY: [u8; 256] = {
    let mut array = [0; 256];
    array[0] = b'b';
    array[1] = b'a';
    array[2] = b'd';
    array
};
```

Now, let take a look at the declarative macro solution. There is no way to "count", there is some trick but will not get very far. A proc macro could work.

You could also generate the file with other tools before compiling. For example, you could use Cargo to [generate the file](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#case-study-code-generation) before compiling.